# Memory issue in R

Tags: r

I know there are lots of memory questions about R, but why can it sometimes find room for an object but other times it cant. For instance, I'm running 64 bit R on Linux, on an interactive node with 15gb memory. My workspace is almost empty:

```
 dat <- lsos()
 dat$PrettySize
[1] "87.5 Kb"  "61.8 Kb"  "18.4 Kb"  "9.1 Kb"   "1.8 Kb"   "1.4 Kb"   "48 bytes"
```

The first time I load R after CD'ing into desired directory I can load an Rdata fine. BUt then sometimes I need to reload it and I get the usual:

```
> load("PATH/matrix.RData")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.9 Gb
```

If I can load it once, and there's enough (I assume contiguous) room, then what's going on? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory error while using write.csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768834/memory-error-while-using-write-csv)

Comment: @Metrics, While Gavin's answer is helpful and relevant, it does not solve this issue.

Comment: @ Ricardo: Thanks. I will retract that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that the memory allocation function needs to find contiguous memory for construction of objects (both permanent and temporary) and other processes (R-process or others) may have fragmented the available space. R will not delete an object that is being overwritten until the load process is completed, so even though you think you may be laying new data on top of old data, you are not.